# Dando “Segmentation fault” quando tento abrir arquivos em C

Tags: c, arquivo, fopen

O seguinte código me dá "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" quando tenta abrir o arquivo depois da declaração e preenchimento de uma string com sprintf.

```
//Sem as duas seguintes linhas, o código roda normalmente
char Xseqpath[90];
sprintf(Xseqpath, "%s/xseqpath", mainfile);

FILE *File1 = fopen("ref.fasta", "r");
char *file1char;
int charnumber = 0;
while(fscanf(File1, "%c", &file1char[charnumber]) != EOF)
{   
    printf("%c\n", file1char[charnumber]);
}
pclose(File1);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é relacionado com alocacao de memoria em C, voce esta inserindo dados no ponteiro `char *file1char` que nao foi alocado, somente declarado.

Substitua a declaracao `char *file1char` por `char file1char[1024]`, tome cuidado pois se seu arquivo `ref.fasta` tiver mais de 1024 bytes ira acontecer invasao de memoria e possivelmente outro sigsegv.

Seu codigo ficaria assim:

```
char Xseqpath[90];
sprintf(Xseqpath, "%s/xseqpath", mainfile);

FILE *File1 = fopen("ref.fasta", "r");
char file1char[1024];

int charnumber = 0;

while(fscanf(File1, "%c", &file1char[charnumber]) != EOF)
    printf("%c\n", file1char[charnumber]);

pclose(File1);

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi respondido aqui, o problema é que você não alocou nenhum espaço na memória para file1char.

Você pode também ter uma abordagem dinâmica sem muita complicação, podendo realizar o processo em arquivos de qualquer tamanho, já que você obtem caracter por caracter:

```
char Xseqpath[90];
sprintf(Xseqpath, "%s/xseqpath", mainfile);

FILE *File1 = fopen("ref.fasta", "r");
char* file1char = calloc(1,sizeof(char)); //calloc é mais seguro que malloc

int charnumber = 0;

while(fscanf(File1, "%c", &file1char[charnumber]) != EOF)
{
    //"charnumber++" retorna o valor anterior de charnumber, e incrementa após retornar.
    printf("%c", file1char[charnumber++]);
    //Aumenta o tamanho de file1char dinâmicamente
    file1char = realloc(file1char,(charnumber+1)*sizeof(char));
}

fclose(File1);
free(file1char);

return 0;
```

Mas se você não precisar deste vetor de caracteres para usar em algo mais tarde, não há necessidade de salvar todo o conteúdo do arquivo em uma string, você pode utilizar apenas um caracter e atribuir sempre a ele:

```
char Xseqpath[90];
sprintf(Xseqpath, "%s/xseqpath", mainfile);

FILE *File1 = fopen("ref.fasta", "r");
char file1char; //1 caracter

int charnumber = 0;

while(fscanf(File1, "%c", &file1char) != EOF) //Salva sobrescrevendo
    printf("%c", file1char);

fclose(File1);

return 0;
```